# getting null value when trying to access a string using widget.string in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get the firebase auth exception for logging in with email and password. In my app, all the auth services is in a class AuthService in another file authservice.dart and i want to get the exception from there to my loginscreen class in another file

this is the class in my authservice.dart file

the exception works here and im able to print it to the console.

```
 class AuthService {
//  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
//  UserModel _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
//    return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

 // Stream<UserModel> get user {
 //   return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
 // }


  Future loginWithEmailpasswd(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      StudentLoginScreen(
        message: e.toString(), // passing  the exception
      );
    }
  }
```

this is my loginscreen class

```
class StudentLoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  final String message;
  StudentLoginScreen({this.toggleView, this.message});

  @override
  _StudentLoginScreenState createState() => _StudentLoginScreenState();
}

final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

class _StudentLoginScreenState extends State<StudentLoginScreen> {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String _message;
  final AuthService _authService = AuthService();
  //SharedPreferences usertype;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: HexColor(studentPrimaryColour),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                showAlert(),       // i want to show the exception message in this widget
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                // HeadingText(
                //   text: 'Login',
                //   size: 60.0,
                //   color: Colors.white,
                // ),
                // RoundedInputField(
                //   hintText: "Email",
                //   validator: (val) =>
                //       val.isEmpty ? 'Oops! you left this field empty' : null,
                //   onChanged: (val) {
                //     email = val;
                //   },
                // ),
                // RoundedInputField(
                //   hintText: "Password",
                //   validator: (val) =>
                //       val.isEmpty ? 'Oops! you left this field empty' : null,
                //   boolean: true,
                //   onChanged: (val) {
                //     password = val;
                //   },
                // ),
                Container(
                      child: FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                          dynamic result = await _authService
                              .loginWithEmailpasswd(email, password);
                          if (result != null) {
                            print('logged in');
                          } else {
                            print('error logging in');
                            setState(() {
                              _message = widget.message;
                            });
                            print(_message);          // its returning a null value
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'login',
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                            color: HexColor(studentPrimaryColour),
                            fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showAlert() {
    if (_message != null) {  //nothing happens here since _message is always null even if an exception
      return Container(      // is thrown in authservice
        color: Colors.amber,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.error_outline_rounded),
            Expanded(
                child: AutoSizeText(
              _message,
              maxLines: 3,
            ))
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return SizedBox(
      height: 0,
    );
  }
}
```

Am I missing any important things here? Im relatively new to flutter and Im finding it hard to pass values from one class to another.

Comment: try to print widget.message insted of _message

Answer (score 0):

try to return the exception instead of pass it in the screen

```
 Future loginWithEmailpasswd(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
 return e;
    }
```

//ScreenLogin

```
 onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                          dynamic result = await _authService
                              .loginWithEmailpasswd(email, password);

                  if (result is bool) {
  
                              if (result) {
                                print('logged in');
                              }}
                 else {
                                print('error logging in');
                                setState(() {
                                  _message =result;
                                });
                                print(result);        
                              }
                            }
                          },
```

Comment: okay, hopefully it works as of now, added `_message =result.toString()`